Physical Properties from Variable Cell Relax Calculations in Quantum ESPRESSO
I want to know what physical quantities can I calculate using the output file of variables cell relax calculations (vc-relax) in Quantum ESPRESSO or using its post processing tools.

Basically using vc-relax, we find the lattice constants of a material which corresponds the minimum of a potential energy surface.
